# Problema ng-click com AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Tenho um botão:

```
<a ng-click="like">Gostar</a>
```

Quando alguém clica nele, efetua a ação e ele é substituído por jQuery por o outro botão:

```
<a ng-click="unlike">Desgostar</a>
```

Porém quando clica nos botões substituídos, eles não efetuam nenhuma ação. A função do `ng-click` não funciona, apenas quando eles são substituídos, quando recarrega a página funciona normal. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o novo conteúdo não passou pelo compilador do Angular.

Este é um exemplo de pré-compilação antes da inserção de conteúdo via jQuery:

```
$("#conteudo").html(
  $compile(
    "<button ng-click='count = count + 1' ng-init='count=0'>Increment</button><span>count: {{count}} </span>"
  )(scope)
);
```

Sugestão - ao invés de manipular os objetos do DOM, controle a visibilidade por dentro do Angular. Exemplo:

```
<a ng-click="like" ng-if="!item.liked">Gostar</a>
<a ng-click="unlike" ng-if="item.liked">Desgostar</a>
```

Assim, sua aplicação exibitá um botão ou o outro dependendo da propriedade `liked` do objeto `item`.